# Why can't I draw a line on this D3.js using angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a graph using the [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) graphical library for Javascript on my webpage. I can draw a line on an SVG using HTML. But when I try to draw a line using javascript, I get: `ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`

I get this even though I have included the D3.js file.

Please tell me how I can get around this problem.

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pdDCfYmCQxX56sBfjfzW?p=preview

Below are my files for your reference.

**Javascript:**

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'] );

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('myState', {url: '/myState', params: {slug: {value: null, squash: true} }, templateUrl: 'my-state-page1.html', controller: 'MyStateCtrl'} );
  } 
);

myApp.controller('MyStateCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      var self = this;

      $scope.$watch(function() {return self.myDataFromAPI}, function (objVal) {
          console.log('objVal = ', objVal);
          x = objVal.origin.split('.');
          console.log("X = ", x)

          var svgContainer = d3.select("body") .append("svg") .attr("width", 1000) .attr("height", 1000); 

          var line = svgContainer.append("line") .attr("x1", x[0]) .attr("y1", x[1]) .attr("x2", x[2]) .attr("y2", x[3]) .attr("stroke-width", 2) .attr("stroke", "black");
        },
        true
      );


      self.httpFailure = function(response) {
        console.log('Failure');
        self.myDataFromAPI = null;
      }

      self.httpSuccess = function(response) {
        console.log('\n\n\nGot the data from the API!');
        self.myDataFromAPI = response.data;
        console.log('\n\n\self.myDataFromAPI =', self.myDataFromAPI);
      }

      $http.get(
        'https://httpbin.org/get'
      ).then(self.httpSuccess, self.httpFailure);
    }
);


myApp.directive('mypMyDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myDataFromAPI: '='
      },
      controller: 'MyStateCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'myStateCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'myD3Diagram.html'
    };
  }
);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    HELLO!
    <div ng-controller="MyStateCtrl as myStateCtrl">
      <myp-my-directive mydatafromapi="myStateCtrl.myDataFromAPI"></myp-my-directive>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**myD3Diagram.html:**

```
<svg id="my_svg_widget" width="500" height="500">
  <line x1="5" y1="5" x2="40" y2="40" stroke="gray" stroke-width="5"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing a non https library.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

it should have been

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

working plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qpPyzIWItiWw5OP8AbBb?p=preview)

Comment: ARGHH!!!! Lousy error message. THANKS!!!

Follow-up question: Instead of appending a new SVG container to the DOM, how can I paint that line on the existing SVG Container? I tried `var svgContainer = document.getElementById("my_svg_widget")` but that didn't work.

Comment: you can do it like this `d3.select("#my_svg_widget").select("line").style("stroke", "red")`
https://plnkr.co/edit/VUSADOQe1DSCGJdYePmb?p=preview